# Cannot connect from R to local Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I installed Spark on my Windows 7 machine following these instructions:
https://edumine.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/how-to-install-apache-spark-on-a-windows-7-environment/

I defined also the system variables:

```
HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop2.6.0
JAVA_HOME = C:\Java
SPARK_HOME = C:\spark-2.2.1
```

It works, since I can run it from cmd:
[image]

Now I would like to connect from RStudio (but R would be an option as well).
I installed the sparklyr package and entered these commands:

```
library(sparklyr) 

sc = spark_connect(master = "local")
```

But RStudio does not manage to connect. Actually it does not show any message, it just keep loading and I can just stop it with the stop button. The same on R.

Note: I did not install a local version of Spark on R with the command:

```
spark_install(version = "2.1.0")
```

as suggested in many guides on internet, since I have already installed it previously. Correct?
What might be wrong in my procedure?